# Can't open files with spaces in them in RubyMine from better_errors gem

Tags: rubymine, better-errors-gem

I'm developing a Rails app on a Mac using the better_errors gem (https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors). I have better_errors configured to open files in RubyMine using the instructions on the Github wiki (BetterErrors.editor='x-mine://open?file=%{file}&line=%{line}' if defined? BetterErrors).

However when I click on a file from the better_errors page, RubyMine gives me a "cannot find file" error every time. The issue is that my project lives under a directory called "Google Drive" (space between "Google" and "Drive").  The file link is being generated as:

```
<a href="x-mine://open?file=%2FUsers%2Fredacted%2FDocuments%2FGoogle+Drive%2FWork%2FReferrer%2FCode%2FPrototype%2Fapp%2Fhelpers%2Fusers_helper.rb&amp;line=6">app/helpers/users_helper.rb</a>
```

RubyMine, in turn, is trying to open the file:

> '/Users/redacted/Documents/Google+Drive/Work/Referrer/Code/Prototype/app/helpers/users_helper.rb'

When the correct syntax should be:

> '/Users/redacted/Documents/Google Drive/Work/Referrer/Code/Prototype/app/helpers/users_helper.rb'

Compare:

```
$ ls -l '/Users/redacted/Documents/Google+Drive/Work/Referrer/Code/Prototype/app/helpers/users_helper.rb'
ls: /Users/redacted/Documents/Google+Drive/Work/Referrer/Code/Prototype/app/helpers/users_helper.rb: No such file or directory
```

Vs:

```
$ ls -l '/Users/redacted/Documents/Google Drive/Work/Referrer/Code/Prototype/app/helpers/users_helper.rb'
-rw-r--r--  1 redacted  staff  282 Apr 11 15:29 /Users/redacted/Documents/Google Drive/Work/Referrer/Code/Prototype/app/helpers/users_helper.rb
```

Any advice on how to workaround this (aside from renaming my Google Drive home directory, which would cause more of a hassle than it's worth).

This obviously isn't the end of the world, but it'd be nice to get files to open automatically in RubyMine.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal, create a symlink:

```
ln -s ~/Google\ Drive/ ~/GD
```

In development.rb:

```
if defined?(BetterErrors)
    BetterErrors.editor = proc { |full_path, line|
      full_path = full_path.sub('Google Drive', 'GD')
      "x-mine://open?file=#{full_path}&line=#{line}"
    }
end
```